# How can I modify export compliance on App Store Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect

I realised I ticked the wrong answer on the app store connect, for an app I am willing to submit. I can't find a way to modify it on the website, can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upload a new version of the build, then modify it.